# Install opencv cannot find lib libswscale

Tags: software-installation, cmake, opencv

I am installing `opencv` on Ubuntu with `cmake`. Because I have no root privilege, the library required is installed in my home directory. I set the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH` to the directory I used, but when I run cmake with:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/my.path -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 -D WITH_CUBLAS=1 -D BUILD_TIFF=ON .
```

it shows:

```
-- checking for module 'gtk+-2.0'
--   package 'gtk+-2.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gtkglext-1.0'
--   package 'gtkglext-1.0' not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
-- checking for module 'libavcodec'
--   package 'libavcodec' not found
-- checking for module 'libavformat'
--   package 'libavformat' not found
-- checking for module 'libavutil'
--   package 'libavutil' not found
-- checking for module 'libswscale'
--   package 'libswscale' not found
-- checking for module 'libavresample'
--   package 'libavresample' not found
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - found
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
-- checking for module 'tbb'
--   package 'tbb' not found
```

I checked the `libswscale.pc` in in the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` and in `CMakeCache.txt`, it find the .so file:

```
//Path to a library.
FFMPEG_SWSCALE_LIB:FILEPATH=/my/path/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswscale.so
```

Could any one tell my why it says not found?